# Change URIEncoding in OpenShift JBoss AS 7

Tags: java, openid, jboss7.x, openshift

I am building an testing app with Spring Security using the OpenId module. I also use the [jQuery OpenId plugin](http://jvance.com/pages/JQueryOpenIDPlugin.xhtml) to support some providers.

I am testing the app with Tomcat (version 7) and after a little bit of troubleshooting I found that I need to specify the URI encoding for the server in order to support users whose credentials have tilded letters and vowels e.g. Peñasco, Ángel, etc.

In Tomcat I just have to set this to the `tomcat-server.xml` file:

```
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" SSLEnabled="true" .../>
```

But the app is being deployed in a JBoss AS 7 cartridge on the OpenShift PaaS.

How can I put the analog configuration in this case?

EDIT:

I added the file `.openshift / action_hooks / pre_start_jbossas-7` with this contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Need to set URI encoding to UTF-8 because of Spring Security OpenID module needs it for tilded letters e.g. ñ, Á

export JAVA_OPTS=" -Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING=\"UTF-8\" -Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING=true"
```

But it does not work remotely, I used the same options with the local server and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JBoss AS7, you can configure this functionality using system properties:

```
-Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING="UTF-8"
-Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING="true"
```

For reference, see: https://community.jboss.org/message/643825#643825

You can also set these in the `<system-properties>` section of `standalone.xml`, but on OpenShift this file is not controlled by your application.  For an OpenShift app you will need to start JBoss with these options by setting JAVA_OPTS in your application's pre-start hook.  To do this, add the following to the `.openshift/action-hooks/pre_start_jbossas-7` file:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING=\"UTF-8\" \
                  -Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING=\"true\""
```

Hope this helps.  Please leave a comment if you run into issues.

Comment: Openshift documentation for action hooks http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_user_guide.html#the-openshift-directory

Answer (score 4):

For me, was helpfull adding the

```
URIEncoding="UTF-8"
```

into .openshift\config\server.xml in

```
<Connector address="${OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_IP}"
           port="${OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_HTTP_PORT}"
           protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"/>
```