# Read file utf-8, process and JSP

Tags: java, jsp, utf-8, openshift, lex

I've got these files:

in2.txt:

```
Hello
ñuñííòúçç ùùù

uíúgfl
```

Correct output (I obtain it in Eclipse (Linux)):

```
Hello
ñuñííòúçç ùùù

uíúgfl
4 ís lèss thàn síx.
```

Notice that:

- The input (file) and the output have 'ñ', 'í',...
- '4' (in the output) is the number of lines of the input (file).
- The output has the characters 'í', 'è',...

In a JSP file I want to get the correct output (at OpenShift.com), with a process. So, I need to improve my files (JAVA and JSP). So, the JSP file should show me the correct output (also if I redirect the process to out2.txt). Currently I get '?' or another strange characters. Also I've tried, unsuccessful:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
out.print(content);
```

**EDIT:** My JSP file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01   Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head></head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Try 2</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</head>
<body>
   <% ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", "java fileReader2");
       Process process = pb.start();
       // Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java fileReader2");
       while (process.waitFor()!=0){}; 
       InputStream shellIn = process.getInputStream();
       Writer writer = new StringWriter();
       int num=1;
       char[] buffer=new char[num];
       try { 
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(shellIn,"UTF-8"));
            int n;
            while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                  writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
       }
       finally{
             shellIn.close();
       }  
       String str = writer.toString();%>
       <form>
       <TEXTAREA NAME="textarea2" ROWS="15" COLS="1024" readonly="readonly"><%=str %>
       </TEXTAREA>             
       </form>
</body>
```

Incorrect output at OpenShift.com:

```
Hello
�u������� ���


u��
5 ?s l?ss th?n s?x.
```

Notice that:

1. The characters 'gfl' are missing.
2. I've obtained a line more (4+1=5).
3. It appears strange characters and '?'s.

My JAVA file:

```
import java.io.*;
public class fileReader2{
public static void main (String argsv[]){
try{
   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("in2.txt");
   String content="";
   InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis,"utf8");         
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);       
   String line; 
   int i=0;     
   while((line = br.readLine()) != null){       
       i++;
       content=content.concat(line).concat("\n");
    }      

     PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
     out.print(content);

     if (i<6){
        System.out.print(i+" ís lèss thàn síx.");
     }
     fis.close();
   }catch(Exception e1){} 
}
}
```

**EDIT 2:** I found:

- [Change URIEncoding in OpenShift JBoss AS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353342/change-uriencoding-in-openshift-jboss-as-7)
- https://developer.jboss.org/message/643825

My standalone.xml is at '.../jbossas/standalone/configuration', and contains:

```
...
</extensions> 
-<system-properties> 
   <property name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION" value="on"/>
</system-properties>
...
```

I added 2 new properties in this XML file, but nothing occurs, for now. I didnt't find the file domain.xml (and either '.openshift/action-hooks/pre_start_jbossas-7').

**Edit (24 APR):** I've created a new CLASS file, with this future String (Java code), or as a example:

```
String s= "\u00F1ñ"
... // Code
```

This futurist String has 7 characters. I want to see this output in a JSP (a process calls to my CLASS file). As I told you, I've created a new CLASS file, with only a char ('ñ'). In my JSP file I obtain:

```
241
\u00F1
```

I wish:

```
241
ñ
```

NOTE: 241 is %d of 'ñ'.

I intend to do that, transforming all characters to UTF-8, but not a false unicode ("\uXXXX"), for example. I need ideas.

**Edit (28 APR):** My final objective is with JLex (an example code):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
%%
%{
public static void main (String argv [])
throws java.io.IOException {
if (argv.length != 1) {
System.out.println("Usage:");
System.out.println("\tjava fileReader filename.txt");
return ;
} else {
String fInName = argv [0];
if (!fInName.endsWith(".txt")) fInName = fInName + ".txt";
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(fInName);
//Create lexical analyzer
fileReader yy = new fileReader (input);
//Process input file
while (yy.yylex()!=-1);
// Show stats
}
} //End main
%}
%class fileReader
%unicode
%line
%eof{
  if ((yyline+1)<6){
     System.out.println();
     System.out.print((yyline)+" ís lèss thàn síx.");
  }
%eof}
%integer
%state 
break=[\r\n]
%%
<YYINITIAL>{break} { System.out.print(yytext()); }
<YYINITIAL>. { System.out.print(yytext()); }
```

At OpenShift.com I obtain this:

```
Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /1x2/try_utf8.jsp.

Reason: Error reading from remote server



--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at jlex1x2-uocpfc.rhcloud.com Port 80
```

At Linux it runs OK. How to solve this?

Comment: Have you added character set UTF-8 in your JSP pages?

Answer (score 0):

Pls add utf-8 encoding on your jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you do not get UTF-8 (the right locale) in the bash shell or even the fileReader2 does not work correctly.
You can test the UTF-8 output by writing in the JSP source `\u00F1` which is `ñ`.

You'll need [Linux nerds](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22435/how-to-fix-character-encoding-in-bash-arch-linux). Or immediately do:

```
File file = File.createTempFile("fR2-", null);
PrintStream oldOut = System.out;
try (PrintStream capture = new PrintStream(file, "UTF-8")) {
    System.setOut(capture);
    fileReader2.main(new String[0]);
    System.out.flush();
} finally {
    System.setOut(oldOut);
} // closes capture.
```

This creates a PrintStream writing to a (temporary) file. To memory would be better. It uses UTF-8, so all Unicode may be used.

Then `System.setOut` sets following output to the capture.

```
String str = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
file.delete();
```

Comment: My JSP file and fileReader2.class are at OpenShift.com. I understand your code. I never I've used an instruction in a try ( try (instruction) { ). fileReader2.main(...)? Sorry, I missed. If my fileReader2.java is not correct I would like to create a good code, and with my JSP file... Could you extend me your code? It's possible tu put the instruction 'PrintStream capture' above the 'PrintStream oldOut'? Thanks.

Comment: I fine-tuned the code a bit, with explanation. The flush a bit dubious as close flushes. Depends a bit on the order around setOut. Maybe you want to call `setOut(oldOut)` _before_ the `capture.close()`,

Comment: Sorry, but I still do not understand your code. I edited again my question.

Comment: `\u00F1` in a java source or JSP should get you a `ñ`. The problem more seems to be that any kind of console (ProcessBuilder, eclipse, shell) has its own encoding, one has to check. A Linux forum might give better tips.

Comment: How to solve my problem at OpenShift.com? My process creates (at OpenShift.com) a bad file output.txt if my command is 'java fileReader2 > output.txt'. At Linux it runs OK.

Comment: Do `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 ...`. Evidently fileReader2 is not written portable; you compare their output.txt's, when run elsewhere.

Comment: It's possible a code without redirecting the output to a file (tmp, txt,...)? Having a process this process should content the correct output, but I get a bad output.

Comment: If its System.out / stdout is limited to a ISO-8859-1 encoding, writing will loose some chars becoming `?` or such. You can try that outside the concerned application: try whether bash handles everything fine, and investigate what is needed (setlocale or so) to fix any short-coming.

Comment: Try small tests to gain an insight. Use chars from Character Map or such, take care that the used font can show them (HTML) etcetera.

Comment: With processBuilder (ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", "java  -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 fileReader2 in2.1x2 > out.txt");) & start()... the content of the file is 'Hello
�u������� ���


u��
5 ís lèss thàn síx.'.

Comment: Bad file out.txt with some chars, and 4+1 = lines. Without redirecting the output to a TXT, also it appears correctly 'ís lèss thàn síx.'.

Comment: With 'Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash -c java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 fileReader2 in2.1x2 > out.txt");'   Proxy Error.

Comment: In summary, java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 .... it's not a 100% solution. I need to get a complet JSP file for trying it.

Comment: At my side I am at the end of my wits. Instead of bash you might invoke the `java` executable and use `pb.setOutputRedirect(...)` and use also extended Latin `ĉ`= `\u0109` as a visible `à` could simply be Latin-1. The problem is a bit self-inflicted, as one can use java classes in ones JSP; a "library" of one class would suffice. And one even could substitute the System.out by a real Writer/OutputStream.